# install nextcloud on nas4free or raspbian?

Tags: nas, freenas, raspbian, nextcloud

I was going to install nextcloud on my raspberry. This is an easy task but there's also the possibility to install nas4free as the OS instead of raspbian and then install nextcloud as an add-on.

Does nextcloud support some basic NAS features such as RAID and scalability? Will it control the health of my drives? Or could I get these features through raspbian?

Basically, as a private user, I'm trying to decide whether it is worth the effort to install nextcloud on nas4free (or similar) or if it's just as good to take the easiest approach and install it raspbian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does nextcloud support some basic NAS features such as RAID and scalability?

RAID - No, scalability - Yes, it support multi-bucket Object Store.

> Will it control the health of my drives?

No. It usually controlled by specialized applications such as [SMART monitor tools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) that runs as operation system's daemon.

> Or could I get these features through Raspbian?

Yes, RAID as well health monitoring and NAS features can be done on Raspbian.

> I'm trying to decide whether it is worth the effort to install nextcloud on nas4free (or similar) or if it's just as good to take the easiest approach and install it Raspbian?

I afraid you comparing apples, oranges and barbecue...
While [nas4free](http://www.nas4free.org/) and [Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/) kind of comparable in terms that both are operation systems, [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/) is web based application written in PHP language that runs on top of some operation system and can run with Raspbian and nas4free.

Let start from Raspbian, it as a bare operation system that can be customized as you liked, but out of the box it isn't NAS.

nas4free can be installed on Raspberry Pi as dedicated NAS, you even can  utilize its great ZFS feature. It has nice web interface to control most of NAS features plus it comes with many already preinstalled services such SMB/CIFS(windows share), FTP, TFTP, SSH, NFS, AFP(Apple's share), rsycn, unison, syncthing, UPnP, Itunes/DAAP, DDNS, SNMP, Web server, BitTorrent. Since it is based on FreeBSD operation system you may install practically any additional packages from FreeBSD repositories (but don't forget that Raspberry Pi isn't so powerful computer and can be easy overloaded with too many software running in the same time).

There is another project - FreeNAS, similar to nas4free(actually original name of nas4free was FreeNAS before original developer passed trade mark to commercial iXsystems company who rewrote it from scratch and distributing  it as open source) FreeNAS targeting mostly huge projects and would require decent powerful computer. It also has the same features as nas4free, but to compare to nas4free it can't run as embedded NAS.

Another popular NAS is [OpenMediaVault](http://www.openmediavault.org/) designed by one of previously  leading developer of nas4free(actually it called FreeNAS then he work on project and before this name wasn't taken off from project) who leaved nas4free project and created from scratch similar to FreeNAS and nas4free web based NAS that based on debian operation system. It also decent and popular project, it runs on raspberry Pi and has similar feature as previously described NAS projects.

Back to nextcloud - it's application, not operation system, it can run on top of those projects briefly described above. It was forked from owncloud by creator of owncloud and now actively going forward.  Primary purpose of nextcloud  it is - "Access and share your files, calendars, contacts, communication". File access implemented over web based interface. Its primary goal - simplified web interface with powerful features in backend. nextcloud support a lot of plugins that can expand someones workflow. It can work on Raspberry Pi, but I found it slow for such mini computer as Raspberry Pi. If it's your home based project that doesn't require lightning speed then it may fit your needs.

I hope I gave you a clue about these "apples, oranges and barbecue"

Comment: yep, I think nas4free offers more than I would ever need. So I guess I go with raspbian headless and add the features I need. This is really only a two person home backup and calender project. Raspberry should do - and nas4free goes on the bbq.

Comment: @Philippe If you wouldn't  run network hungry applications that requiring speed  then nas4fre on Raspberry Pi should do its job well